# Python - Sum up all values for repeated data points in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

Suppose I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
    1499371791  3145728
    1499371791  4194304
    1499371792  524288
    1499371794  8912896
    1499371794  3145728
    1499371794  5242880
    1499371795  3145728
    1499371795  5242880
```

I want to be able to sum up all the values in the right column that pertain to the same value in the left column more than once.

For example, since '1499371791' appears twice. I want to be able to write the sum of the two '1499371791' values that appear on the right column back to the file. So I want to make it look like this in the end:

```
    1499371791  7340032  
    1499371792  524288
    1499371794  17301504
    1499371795  8388608
```

Such that there is only one value in the left column that pertains to one value in the right column.

I am unsure as to how I should read, sum up values and write to the file all at the same time. Should I import the data and then split each of these functions up? i.e. read, edit and then write to the file all separately.

I have attempted to use "readlines()" as that goes about creating a list of the lines in the file. Then I have tried to use that list to check duplicate values, but the list returned is not in the best format navigate and subsequently edit.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open('test.txt') as f:
    totals = defaultdict(int)
    for key, value in (map(int, line.strip().split('  ')) for line in f):
        totals[key] += value
    print('\n'.join(sorted(['  '.join(map(str, (key, totals[key]))) 
                            for key in totals])))
```

---

Outputs:

```
1499371791 7340032
1499371792 524288
1499371794 17301504
1499371795 8388608
```

Comment: can you tell me why I get "TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable" at line 5?

Comment: @GiovanniGianni this is because in python3 `map` objects can not be indexed, so trying to subscript the map gives an error. OP tagged the question with `python-2.7`, hence why my answer was acceptable in this case. To make this answer python3 compatible you would need to parse `line` into a `tuple` or a `list`.

Comment: I have made an edit to unpack the items from the map now anyway, for a slightly more elegant answer that is both `python2` and `python3` compatible, should a reader wish to use my answer.

Comment: Ok, nice, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

## Use a dictionary

```
kdic = {}
with open("data2.txt", encoding='utf-8') as data:
    data = data.readlines()
    for d in data:
        d = d.rstrip(" ")
        d = d.split()
        try:
            kdic[d[0]] = int(d[1]) + int(kdic[d[0]])
        except KeyError:
            kdic[d[0]] = int(d[1])
print(kdic)

for k,v in kdic.items():
    print(k,"\t",v)
```

> output

```
{'1499371791': 7340032, '1499371792': 524288, '1499371794': 17301504, '1499371795': 8388608}

1499371791   7340032
1499371792   524288
1499371794   17301504
1499371795   8388608
```

### Write the results in a txt file

```
with open("data3.txt","w",  encoding="utf-8") as data:
    for k,v in kdic.items():
        data.write(k + "\t" + str(v) + "\n")
```

***you will have a data3.txt file with this output***

```
1499371791  7340032
1499371792  524288
1499371794  17301504
1499371795  8388608
```

> ### Code with functions

I made some changes to use functions and to create something more complex.

> creadic - creates the dictionary from the file data2.txt
>
> seevalues - shows the values of the dict
>
> writefile - takes 2 args, the first is the file where the data are, they are summed and then written in file2

```
def creadic(datafile):
    'This creates the dictionary'
    kdic = {}
    with open(datafile, encoding='utf-8') as data:
        data = data.readlines()
        for d in data:
            d = d.rstrip(" ")
            d = d.split()
            try:
                kdic[d[0]] = int(d[1]) + int(kdic[d[0]])
            except KeyError:
                kdic[d[0]] = int(d[1])
    print("Dictionary created")
    return kdic

# dizio = creadic("data2.txt")
def seevalues(dic):
    'shows the values in the console'
    for k,v in dic.items():
        print(k,"\t",v)

def writefile(file1,file2):
    'sums the value in file1 and writes the summed ones in file2'
    kdic = creadic(file1)
    seevalues(kdic)
    with open(file2, "w",  encoding="utf-8") as data:
        for k,v in kdic.items():
            data.write(k + "\t" + str(v) + "\n")
    print("Data written")

writefile("data2.txt","data3.txt")
```

> output on console

```
Dictionary created
1499371791   7340032
1499371792   524288
1499371794   17301504
1499371795   8388608
Data written
```

> output on file2

```
1499371791  7340032
1499371792  524288
1499371794  17301504
1499371795  8388608
```

## Choosing data in different steps

```
"""
This are the data in data1.txt

1499371791  3145728
1499371791  4194304
1499371792  524288
1499371794  8912896
1499371794  3145728
1499371794  5242880
1499371795  3145728
1499371795  5242880
1499371797  3242880
1499371800  1242880
1499371800  2442880
1499371803  2442880
"""
```

#### This is the code

```
def creadic(datafile):
    'This creates the dictionary'
    global start
    kdic = {}
    with open(datafile, encoding='utf-8') as data:
        data = data.readlines()

        for d in data:
            d = d.rstrip(" ")
            d = d.split()
            start = int(d[0].rstrip())
            try:
                kdic[d[0]] = int(d[1]) + int(kdic[d[0]])
            except KeyError:
                kdic[d[0]] = int(d[1])
    return kdic

# dizio = creadic("data2.txt")
def seevalues(dic):
    'shows the values in the console'
    for k,v in dic.items():
        print(k,"\t",v)

def writefile(file1,file2):
    'sums the value in file1 and writes the summed ones in file2'
    kdic = creadic(file1)
    seevalues(kdic)
    with open(file2, "w",  encoding="utf-8") as data:
        for k,v in kdic.items():
            data.write(k + "\t" + str(v) + "\n")
    print("Data written")

def writefile2(file1,file2,step):
    'sums the value in file1 and writes the summed ones in file2'
    global start
    kdic = creadic(file1)
    print("Data in console:")
    with open(file2, "w",  encoding="utf-8") as data:
        for k,v in kdic.items():
            if int(k)%(start+step)%3==0:
                data.write(k + "\t" + str(v) + "\n")
                print(k,v)
    print("This data has been written in {}".format(file2))

writefile2("data1.txt","data2.txt",3)
```

> #### Output
>
> ```
> Data in console:
> 1499371800 3685760
> 1499371797 3242880
> 1499371791 7340032
> 1499371794 17301504
> 1499371803 2442880
> This data has been written in data2.txt
> ```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean, please ( make an example too)?

Comment: What would be the best way to group the output in file2 into intervals of suppose 3? 

For example, if the output on file2 is:  

        1499371791  7340032  
        1499371792  524288  
        1499371794  17301504  
        1499371795  8388608  
        1499371797  8799002  

And I wanted a final output of:  

        1499371791  7340032  
        1499371794  17301504  
        1499371797  8799002

Comment: Ok, so you want to skip 1 row... let me try

Comment: Not necessarily one row, just skip everything in between intervals of 3 on the left column.. so if it starts with 1499371791, then only keep data values with an offset of a multiple of 3 from it. Like 1499371794, 1499371797 etc.. and ignore the rest.

Comment: So (writing the last number): 1,4,7,10, 13, 16 and so on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149027/discussion-between-adivk-and-giovanni-gianni).

Answer (score 0):

You can read the txt file as CSV, and define the space between the tow columns as delimiter. Something like:

```
import unicodecsv

# ...

with open(csvfile_entry, 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = unicodecsv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='"', quoting=unicodecsv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in spamreader:
        # you logic goes here
```

So this will read the the whole file and add the necessary rows to a variable and have to sum up the values if the next "key" is part of the already processed rows.

Answer (score 0):

The python package "pandas" is most helpful to these kinds of operations. Do take care that in the example below the text file contained no leading spaces and takes exactly a double spacing between the columns. Adjust to your own text file specs for optimum result.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("test.txt", header = None, sep='  ', engine='python')
df = df.set_index(0)
df = df.groupby(df.index).sum()
In [22]: df

Out[22]: 
                   1
0                   
1499371791   7340032
1499371792    524288
1499371794  17301504
1499371795   8388608
```